# Can't see product of sub categories when clicking parent category in woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, product, categories

I'm building ecommerce site with woocommerce. I divided sub categories under the parent category. I upload product on each sub categories and choose not only sub category but also parent category. But, when I clicking parent category, I can't see any product. I can see only in sub categories.For example, I have "watches & accessories" as a parent category and I have "women's watches,men's watches" as a sub categories. I upload product according to each sub categories by choosing sub category and parent category in it "product categories". I want to show products not only in sub categories but also in it parent category. Let me know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on a clean install of WordPress with WooCommerce:

- Add a category, 'Category A'
- Add a subcategory, 'Subcategory B'
- Add a product, 'Product 1'
- Assign product to both Category A and Subcategory B
- View 'Category A' listing page

The product showed up on the Category A listing page.